# Do I need a custom Spliterator to avoid extra .stream() call?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this code which works fine, but I find it ugly.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class Actions {

    @Getter
    private List<ActionsBloc> blocs;

    public Actions mergeWith(@NotNull Actions other) {

        this.blocs = Stream.of(this.blocs, other.blocs)
                                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                    .collect(groupingBy(ActionsBloc::getClass, reducing(ActionsBloc::mergeWith)))
                                    .values()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                    .map(Optional::get)
                                    .collect(toList());

        return this;
    }
}
```

`ActionsBloc` is a super type which contains a list of `Action`.

```java
public interface ActionsBloc {

    <T extends Action> List<T> actions();

    default ActionsBloc mergeWith(ActionsBloc ab) {
        this.actions().addAll(ab.actions());
        return this;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is merge `blocs` of `Actions` together based on the `Class` type. So I'm grouping by `ActionsBloc::getClass` and then merge by calling `ActionsBloc::mergeWith`.

What I find ugly is calling the `values().stream()` after the first stream was ended on `collect`.

Is there a way to operate only on one stream and get rid of `values().stream()`, or do I have to write a custom Spliterator? In other words have only one `collect` in my code.

Comment: What does the `ActionsBloc::mergeWith` look like? What is `ActionsBloc`?

Comment: @Naman i've updated my post. I wont put the code of `Action` because it's 
superfluous for the question.

Comment: as a side note, starting from Java 9 you can replace `.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` with `.flatMap(Optional::stream)`

Comment: @Adrian good to know, hélas i’m using java 8

Comment: @ElmaCherb I think it was answered once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013437/grouping-java8-stream-without-collecting-it) - no, it's not possible to group without collecting

Comment: @Adrian related to that post, i have to write my own spliterator or use a third-party lib

Comment: Just `.collect(toMap(ActionsBloc::getClass, Function.identity(), ActionsBloc::mergeWith))`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a reducing identity to sort that out possibly. One way could be to update the implementation of `mergeWith` as :

```
default ActionsBloc mergeWith(ActionsBloc ab) {
    this.actions().addAll(Optional.ofNullable(ab)
            .map(ActionsBloc::actions)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList()));
    return this;
}
```

and then modify the `grouping` and `reduction` to:

```
this.blocs = new ArrayList<>(Stream.of(this.blocs, other.blocs)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(ActionsBloc::getClass, reducing(null, ActionsBloc::mergeWith)))
        .values());
```

**Edit**: As Holger pointed out such use cases of using `groupingBy` and `reducing` further could be more appropriately implemented using `toMap` as :

```
this.blocs = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(this.blocs.stream(), other.blocs.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ActionsBloc::getClass, Function.identity(), ActionsBloc::mergeWith))
        .values());
```

Comment: your solution is good but i’ll have the same problem when filtering on empty lists. This way i will have 2 calls to collect too.

Comment: @ElmaCherb Seems like you're looking for [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)). Is that so, maybe I've understood the problem incorrectly?

Comment: I have to try it, i don’t know if i can get rid of the second stream inside collectAndThen

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using the `reducing` collector with `groupingBy`, you should check whether `toMap` isn’t more appropriate: `.collect(toMap(ActionsBloc::getClass, Function.identity(), ActionsBloc::mergeWith))` or `.collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(ActionsBloc::getClass, Function.identity(), ActionsBloc::mergeWith), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())))`. Further, this looks like a job for `Stream.concat(this.blocs.stream(), other.blocs.stream())`…

Comment: @Holger it works like a charm with `collectingAndThen`, you can put your solution and i'll choose it as the correct one. Can you add some references about the use of `reducing` and `groupingBy` together ? it seems like a pattern

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the note. Would try and practice the pattern going forward. `Stream.concat` makes sense as well.